# Calculate difference in date in this date format MMM-YYYY

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with dates in following format:

Initial:

```
Jan-2015 Apr-2013 Jun-2014 Jan-2015 Jan-2016 Jan-2015 Jan-2016 Jan-2015 Apr-2012 Nov-2012 Jun-2013 Sep-2013
```

Final:

```
Feb-2014 Jan-2013 Sep-2014 Apr-2013 Sep-2014 Mar-2013 Aug-2012 Apr-2012 Oct-2012 Oct-2013 Jun-2014 Oct-2013
```

I would like to perform these steps:

1. create dummy variables for Month and Year
2. Subtract these dates from another dates to find out duration (final- initials) in months

I would like to do these in R?

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @neilfws answer, you can use the `month` and `year` functions from the `lubridate` package to create your dummy variables with the month and year in your data frame.

Here is the code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(Initial = c("Jan-2015", "Apr-2013", "Jun-2014", "Jan-2015", "Jan-2016", "Jan-2015", 
                         "Jan-2016", "Jan-2015", "Apr-2012", "Nov-2012", "Jun-2013", "Sep-2013"),
             Final = c("Feb-2014", "Jan-2013", "Sep-2014", "Apr-2013", "Sep-2014", "Mar-2013", 
                       "Aug-2012", "Apr-2012", "Oct-2012", "Oct-2013", "Jun-2014", "Oct-2013"))

df$Initial <- as.character(df$Initial)
df$Final <- as.character(df$Final)
df$Initial <- as.yearmon(df$Initial, "%b-%Y")
df$Final <- as.yearmon(df$Final, "%b-%Y")
df$month_initial <- month(df$Initial)
df$year_intial <- year(df$Initial)
df$month_final <- month(df$Final)
df$year_final <- year(df$Final)

df$Difference <- 12*(df$Initial-df$Final)
```

And here is the final data.frame:

```
> head(df)
   Initial    Final month_initial year_intial month_final year_final Difference
1 Jan 2015 Feb 2014             1        2015           2       2014         11
2 Apr 2013 Jan 2013             4        2013           1       2013          3
3 Jun 2014 Sep 2014             6        2014           9       2014         -3
4 Jan 2015 Apr 2013             1        2015           4       2013         21
5 Jan 2016 Sep 2014             1        2016           9       2014         16
6 Jan 2015 Mar 2013             1        2015           3       2013         22
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `as.yearmon` from the `zoo` package for this.

```
library(zoo)
12 * (as.yearmon("Jan-2015", "%b-%Y") - as.yearmon("Feb-2014", "%b-%Y"))

# result
# [1] 11
```